# BCP hang when executed through trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008, bcp, xp-cmdshell

When I executes this command, it works!

```
DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(1000) 
SET @CMD = 'cd.. && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe" "SELECT TOP 1 CODE FROM[TABLE] WITH (NOLOCK) ORDER BY ID DESC" queryout "\\FOLDER\FOLDER\FILE.txt" -T -c -S "[SERVERNAME]"'
EXEC master..XP_CMDSHELL @CMD
```

But, if I executes that from a trigger, it hangs! And I have to restart the services

```
ALTER TRIGGER [TRIGGER] on [TABLE] after INSERT AS BEGIN
DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(1000) 
SET @CMD = 'cd.. && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe" "SELECT TOP 1 CODE FROM[TABLE] WITH (NOLOCK) ORDER BY ID DESC" queryout "\\FOLDER\FOLDER\FILE.txt" -T -c -S "[SERVERNAME]"'
EXEC master..XP_CMDSHELL @CMD END
```

Somebody knows why??

Comment: `xp_cmdshell` only has the permissions of the SQL Service Account. Does it have permissions to the paths specified. Also, why are you doing `cd..`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely in deadlock trying to access the table from `bcp` while processing a trigger from the same table you are trying to insert.

Think of it like this: The trigger waits for bcp, that is waiting for a lock on the table to be released, but that lock is held until after the trigger.

Comment: The porpuse of the trigger is exporting an specific data from a table with bcp after inserting data on that table, so I thought doing it in that way, do you know how I can do it? or do I need to add some function or something for that works?

Comment: Please post as a different question